# What causes the chirping sound coming from my 250 natural gas meter?

Tags: natural-gas, meter

When gas is flowing through the meter, I hear a steady, slow chirping sound (perhaps a chirp every 5 to 10 seconds).  Is this an indication that the meter (35 years old) is coming to the end of its life?  Should I be concerned about the chirping?

Comment: Methane-breathing crickets!

Answer (score 6):

The noise is likely caused by a moving part rubbing its bearing or keeper. Whether or not it's a problem will depend on the meter.

You should contact the utility, and let them decide how to proceed.  In most places the utility owns the meter, and is responsible for maintaining and/or replacing them.

Comment: I plan on putting in a natural gas standby generator.  Is it likely I could talk Con Ed into putting in a larger meter rather than just putting in a new 250? That would save me money since I will need a larger meter for the standby gen.

Comment: You'd have to ask them that when you call. I'd suspect that if you want to upgrade the service, they'd have to upgrade the supply piping. Though that's a guess, as I'm not familiar with Con Ed's service piping practices. If it's as simple as installing a different meter, I'd suspect they'd do it. However, if they have to install new service lines, they'll likely charge you. Keep in mind, this is all speculation, as I don't know anything about Con Ed's business practices.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, call the utility & they'll have it swapped out in maybe 10-minutes & they'll probably be out next day. Your concern is that they can't accurately charge you & will estimate your bill with a wholly illegal & unwritten surcharge.